# jquery regular expression match

Tags: jquery, regex

How can I structure my regular expression `".*\\|" + movingReportInstID` to match this: `49|25` but not this `75|258` where `movingReportInstID = 25`

Code usage below

```
set movingReportInstID = 25
for(i = 0; i < origOrderArr.length; ++i){
    if(origOrderArr[i].match(".*\\|" + movingReportInstID)) {
        var origLocation = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use word boundaries `\b` with `RegExp` constructor.

Comment: That is what I am using. Javascript would be fine as well

Comment: @Tushar - if you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.  That was what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `^` and `$`to assert position at start and end of the string:

```
origOrderArr[i].match("^.*\\|" + movingReportInstID + "$")
```